# Using Sqoop to load HBase tables , Data not visible via Phoenix

Tags: hbase, fetch, sqoop, apache-phoenix

Looking for some help in the following scenario -

- I have created on Phoenix table which created underneath HBase table.
- Then used sqoop command to move data from relational database database table (Teradata) to underneath HBase table successfully
- I can view the data through HBase but it is not visible in Phoenix table.

What I am missing here ?

Regards
Manya

Comment: Did you find a cause of the problem? I have the same problem with Pentaho DI->Calcite JDBC Driver->Query Server.

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix will be supported in Sqoop 1.4.7
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2649